# Is it possible to read in a whole folder of csv files using one line of read code in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have about 20 csv files that I need to read in, is it possible to read in the whole folder instead of doing them individually? I am using python. Thanks

Comment: can't you use `os.listdir()`  or `glob.glob('path/*.csv')` and `for`-loop to read all files ? If you put it in function then you can run this function in one line.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [The `fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) almost meets your needs, allowing you to pretend a bunch of files are a single file, but it also doesn't meet the requirements of files for the `csv` module (namely, that newline translation must be turned off). Just open the files one-by-one and append the results of parsing to a single `list`; it's not that much more effort. No matter what you do *something* must "do them individually"; there is no magic to say "read 20 files exactly as if they were one file". Even fobbing off to `cat` or the like (to concatenate all the files into a single stream you can read from) is just shunting the same file-by-file work elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull a list of files in Python by using `os.listdir`. From there, you can loop over your list of files, and generate a list of CSV files:

```
import os
filenames = os.listdir("path/to/directory/")
csv_files = []
for name in filenames:
    if filename.endswith("csv"):
        csv_files.append(name)
```

From there, you'll have a list containing every CSV in your directory.

Comment: I'd strongly discourage a test like `filename[-3:] == "csv"`; magic numbers that implicitly rely on other information (e.g. the length of the string being compared to in this case) are a common source of errors (e.g. if someone changes the string being compared to `".csv"` and forgets to update the slice size, the test is completely broken). Use string methods like `filename.endswith("csv")`, they're safer and more self-documenting.

Comment: Oh hey, didn't even know that was a method. Thanks, I've updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The shortest thing that I can think of is this, it's not in one line because you have to import a bunch of stuff so that line is not that long:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile
from os.path import splitext
from os.path import join
import pandas as pd

source = '/tmp/'
dfs = [
    pd.read_csv(join(source, path)) for path in listdir(source) if isfile(join(source, path)) and splitext(join(source, path))[1] == '.csv'
]
```